# Mern Stack : Passport.js google auth not working in production (heroku and firebase)

Tags: firebase, heroku, oauth-2.0, passport.js, mern

My application works as expected in localhost but when I deploy express backend to **heroku** and react frontend to **firebase** the google authentication stop working.

In **heroku** logs , I get the user profile from google and I get user logged from serialize and deserialize functions but when I make a request to get current user I get undefined.

For some reason the server is not setting the cookies in the browser , I can't find any session cookie when I open the cookies in storage in the browser.

I tried every possible solution I found in the internet but the problem persists.

**Edit**

I moved my frontend to heroku and removed domain from cookie options , this time it worked but only in private mode , any idea about why its not working in normal mode?

here is the code:

**server.js**

```
import express from "express";
import mongoose from "mongoose";
import passport from "passport";
import "./passport.js";
import routerLogin from "./routes/auth.js";
import routerUser from "./routes/user.js";
import cookieSession from "cookie-session";
import cookieParser from "cookie-parser";


import { createRequire } from "module"; 
const require = createRequire(import.meta.url);

require("dotenv").config();
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");

const morgan = require("morgan"); 

import cors from "cors";

const app = express();
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(
  cors({
    origin: "https://appname-339620.firebaseapp.com",
    credentials: true,
    methods: "GET,HEAD,PUT,PATCH,POST,DELETE",
  })
);
app.use(bodyParser.json());


// db connection
mongoose
  .connect(process.env.DATABASE, {
    useNewUrlParser: true,
    useUnifiedTopology: true,
  })
  .then(() => console.log("DB Connected"))
  .catch((err) => console.log("DB Connection Error: ", err));

//middlewares
app.use(morgan("dev"));
app.use(express.json());

app.set("trust proxy", 1);

app.use(
  cookieSession({
    name: "SocialMedia-auth-session",
    secret: process.env.SESSION_SECRET,
    httpOnly: true,
    secure: true,
    sameSite: "none",
    domain: "https://appname-339620.firebaseapp.com/", 
  })
);

app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());

// routes
app.use("/", routerLogin);
app.use("/", routerUser);

const port = process.env.PORT || 8000;
app.listen(port, () => console.log(`the app listening on port ${port}!`));
```

**passport.js**

```
import passport from "passport";
import User from "./models/user.js";
import Google from "passport-google-oauth20";

const GoogleStrategy = Google.Strategy;

import { createRequire } from "module"; 
const require = createRequire(import.meta.url);
require("dotenv").config();

passport.serializeUser((user, done) => {
  console.log("user from serialize", user);
  done(null, user.id);
});

passport.deserializeUser(async (id, done) => {
  const user = await User.findById(id).populate("bookmarks");
  console.log("user from deserialize", user);
  done(null, user);
});

passport.use(
  new GoogleStrategy(
    {
      clientID: process.env.GOOGLE_APP_ID,
      clientSecret: process.env.GOOGLE_APP_SECRET_KEY,
      callbackURL: "/auth/google/callback",
      proxy: true,
    },
    async (accessToken, refreshToken, profile, done) => {
      console.log("profile from google =>", profile); 
      const user = await User.findOne({ GoogleID: profile.id });
      if (!user) {
        const newUser = await User.create({
          GoogleID: profile.id,
          name: profile.displayName,
          email: profile.emails[0].value,
          picture: profile.photos[0].value,
        });
        if (newUser) {
          done(null, newUser);
        }
      } else {
        done(null, user);
      }
    }
  )
);
```

**callback route in auth.js**

```
routerLogin.get(
  "/auth/google/callback",
  passport.authenticate("google", {
    successRedirect: "https://appname-339620.firebaseapp.com", 
    failureRedirect: "https://appname-339620.firebaseapp.com/error",
  })
);
```

**current user Route**

```
routerUser.get("/auth/user", async (req, res) => {
  console.log("req.user =>", req.user); // undefined in production
  res.send(req.user);
});
```

**axios call to current user**

```
useEffect(() => {

    const ourRequest = axios.CancelToken.source();
    const fetchUser = async () => {
      try {
        const res = await axios.get(
          "/auth/user",
          {
            withCredentials: true,
          },
          { cancelToken: ourRequest.token }
        );
        if (res.data) {
          setUser({ user: res.data, loggedIn: true });
        }
       
        }
      } catch (err) {
        setUser({ ...state, userError: true });
        showNotification({  // I get this error notification when I try to connect in production
          color: "red",
          message: "failed to connect ! ",
          autoClose: 5000,

          disallowClose: true,
          icon: <AlertOctagon size={22} strokeWidth={1} color={"white"} />,
        });

      }
    };
    fetchUser();
    return () => ourRequest.cancel;
  }, []);
```

**axios default base URL in app.js**

```
axios.defaults.baseURL = "https://nameapp.herokuapp.com";
```

**Authorized redirect URIs in google settings**
https://nameapp.herokuapp.com/auth/google/callback

Answer (score 0):

My mistake was I forgot to add **https://** in the url bar in normal chrome tab , normal chrome tab doesn't accept cookies when the url is not secure (http) , only incognito mode accept cookies in http.

I also removed domain from cookie option(server.js) when I moved my react app to heroku.(but I think you should keep it when hosting to firebase)

Maybe it wasn't necessary to move from firebase, I believe I was making the same mistake when my frontend was hosted on firebase .. but I'm too lazy to check it now